# What's this old school anime with a badass green-haired Sephiroth lookalike?

Tags: escaflowne

So I remember this scene from an anime for many years now but I can't find it no matter what I searched for.

Here's what I remember:

- Green (maybe blue? not sure) long-haired badass guy, with dark clothing. He really resembles Sephiroth from *Final Fantasy*.
- The setup is in a futuristic city/world, the city I remember resembles the city from *Akira*: flying cars, full of roads, light etc.
- It must be an old anime, late 80s or early 90s.

The scene I remember clearly is this guy walking an empty road on that city, but the screen is full with roads on all heights, buildings etc. I think this guy is accompanied by someone else on that scene but I'm not sure.

I tried to find it many times for 5 years or so, but I cant remember anything else at all.

What is this anime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this possibly the [**Escaflowne (film)**](http://escaflowne.wikia.com/wiki/Escaflowne_movie)? It was made in 2000, adapting a TV anime from 1996.

Folken in the film version has long sky-blue hair and dark clothes, and is the main antagonist (he was born as Dune of Adom but became the leader of the Black Dragon Clan).

[image: Folken]
[image: Folken holding Hitomi]

Allen Schezar in the same film, the leader of the Abaharaki (a group of refugees),  also has Sephiroth-style bangs with long hair and dark clothes.

[image: Allen]
[image]

The film includes airships, roads, and lights.

[image: night scene]
[image: dusk scene]

Comment: the middle set of screen shots on the left the guy really does looks a lot like Sephiroth with his hair and the coat he is wearing. if i didn't know any better and saw that image on google i could confuse it with a screen shot from the animated version of Final Fantasy VII Crisis Core

Comment: Actually this may be it. Not sure though, I will definitly check it out! Thank you so much for the answer.